# How to avoid Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never' when turning an array of objects with required properties into an object with Typescript?

Tags: typescript

Have a look at the following code example:

```
interface Test {
  valueA: string;
  valueB?: boolean;
  valueC?: number;
  valueD?: {};
  valueE?: 'literalA' | 'literalB';
}

let a: {
  key: keyof Test;
  val: any;
}[] = [
  {
    key: 'valueA',
    val: 'test1',
  },
];

let b: Test = {
  valueA: 'test2',
  valueE: 'literalA',
};
b[a[0].key as keyof Test] = a[0].val;
```

Values from Array 'a' are to be assigned as properties to object 'b'. In the example, this is done for the first element in 'a', but ultimately will have do be done for all elements in 'a'.

If all properties of interface 'Test' are set to optional, no error is displayed. If at least one property is set to required (like in the example), Typescript will display the following error:

> Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'

Despite the error, the code executes as expected, so I have tried using Partial to resolve the error making all properties in 'Test' optional with no success.

Ultimately, I would like to keep the required properties in 'Test' as such and find a solution for the Typescript error above.

Any help/advice to resolve this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Partial after all to resolve the error

```
let b: Partial<Test> = {
  valueA: 'test2',
  valueE: 'literalA',
};
```

Other/better solutions which will not turn all properties of 'Test' optional are still much appreciated.